# WPF changing a font family in control code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a resource  dictionary,  saved in a control folder and I need to access it in change my font.
I tried this
 `fontFamily = (FontFamily) Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[1];`
but I got an error .

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' to 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily'

This I my Resources Dictionary :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexic-Regular">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexic-Regular</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexic-Bold">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexic-Bold</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexic-BoldItalic">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexic-BoldItalic</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexic-Italic">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexic-Italic</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexicAlta-Bold">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexicAlta-Bold</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexicAlta-BoldItalic">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexicAlta-BoldItalic</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexicAlta-Regular">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexicAlta-Bold</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexicAlta-Italic">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexicAlta-BoldItalic</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="OpenDyslexicMono-Regular">OpenDyslexicFont\#OpenDyslexicMono-Regular</FontFamily>
```

How do I changed the font using this Class:

```
 public static class FontFamilyDisplayOptionsExtensions
{
    
    public static FontFamily GetFontFamily(FontFamilyDisplayOptions font )
    {
        FontFamily fontFamily;

        switch (font)
        {
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.SegoeUI:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.Modernpic:
                fontFamily = (FontFamily) Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[1]; 
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.Arial:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.comicSans:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("Comic Sans");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.HorrorFonts:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("CSNPWDT NFI");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.OpenDyslexic:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("OpenDyslexic");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.OpenDyslexicAlta:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("OpenDyslexicAlta");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.OpenDyslexicMono:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("OpenDyslexicMono");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.Poppins:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("Poppins");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.PoppinsMedium:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("PoppinsMedium");
                break;
            case FontFamilyDisplayOptions.PoppinsSemiBold:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("PoppinsSemiBold");
                break;
            default:
                fontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
                break;
        }


        return fontFamily;
    }
}
```

Comment: var resource = dictionary["whateverKey"] as WhateverResourceType;
Where in your case the distionary is Application.Current.Resources

Comment: I  this : var resource = Dictionary["OpenDyslexic-Regular"] as FontFamily;  but I get an   Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'Dictionary<TKey, TValue>'

Comment: Does any one know?

Comment: Ok I tried this :   fontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["ModernPictograms"] as FontFamily;     I did not get an error but I am getting junk ...    any Ideas as to why?

Comment: @ Maciek Świszczowski  Am  I not understanding your answered ? did I do it wrong or something, because I am getting a normal font back. I think it is the default  font . It works when I do this FontFamily="/NumberControl;component/#Modern Pictograms"   in the xaml but the code behind is not working.